# Remove Shadow from Popover

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

I'm using JQuery-mobile to implement a popover for my buttons. My goal is to remove the shadow behind the popover. How can i accomplish this?

[image]

**Reference:** http://api.jquerymobile.com/popup/#option-shadow

```css
.ui-content {
  shadow: false
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>


<div data-role="main" class="ui-content">

  <a href="#myPop1" data-rel="popup" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline">Click Me to display popup</a>
  <a href="#myPop1" data-rel="popup" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline">Click Me to display popup</a>
  <a href="#myPop1" data-rel="popup" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline">Click Me to display popup</a>
  <a href="#myPop1" data-rel="popup" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline">test</a>


  <div data-role="popup" id="myPop1" class="ui-content" data-arrow="l,t">
    <p>Awesome <strong>popup!</strong></p>
  </div>


</div>
```

Comment: Please add `.ui-overlay-shadow {
  box-shadow: none;
 }`

Comment: ahh thank you it worked!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It adds box-shadow, so you can just remove that.

```
#myPop1 {
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

Or in general if you want to override it completely:

```
.ui-overlay-shadow {
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

Also beware it adds text-shadow too so you can remove that the same way if you want

Answer (score 3):

Can we see your initialising JS? `shadow: false` isn't CSS and so won't work in your example code.

Try adding `data-shadow="false"` to your popup div, as such-

```
<div data-role="popup" id="myPop1" data-shadow="false" class="ui-content" data-arrow="l,t">
  <p>Awsome <strong>popup!</strong></p>
</div>
```

or add `shadow: false` into wherever you call `.popup()`-

```
$( "#myPop1" ).popup({
  shadow: false
});
```

Hop this helps!

Comment: good answer, upvote! i'm wonder where the CSS comes from, given the JQM reference page (?)

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to get a "flat" JQM Popup (without any box-shadow) in CSS:

```css
.ui-popup-container * {
  -moz-box-shadow: none !important;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none !important;
  box-shadow: none !important;
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>


<div data-role="main" class="ui-content">

  <a href="#myPop1" data-rel="popup" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline">Click Me to display popup</a>


  <div data-role="popup" id="myPop1" class="ui-content" data-arrow="l,t">
    <p>Awesome <strong>popup!</strong></p>
            <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all" data-rel="back">OK</a>
  </div>


</div>
```

Cross-browser, works for dynamically created elements, and also for contained elements, for example Buttons or Listviews.
Alternatively, use the suggested approach in the answer from [Daniel Davies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43374785/4845566)

Answer (score -1):

When you activate the hover.. (.hover? .click?) However you do that. Add this code in that function:

```
$('.ui-content').css('text-shadow','0');
```

Or if you can't find that function you could just add a custom:

```
$('.blah').on('hover', function(){ $('.ui-content').css('text-shadow','0'); });
```

Comment: I woudn't use jQuery for a css problem, even though it's jQuery UI that's adding the style to begin with

Comment: just added an answer in CSS to your thoughts. try it out and enjoy! (of course, for text-shadow, you are right, but this could be also done in CSS)